# Error when using Application.currentApplication() in JavaScript for Automation (OSA)

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, osascript, javascript-automation

When using `Application.currentApplication()` in an OSA script, it issues the following warning when running it from the command line:

```
warning: failed to get scripting definition from /usr/bin/osascript; it may not be scriptable.
```

Why is this happening and what can be done about it?

### Example

app.js:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
console.log('Hello, I’m ' + app.pathTo(this));
```

Shell Output:

```
❯❯❯ ./app.js
2015-03-01 12:39:29.611 app.js[65539:6266286] warning: failed to get scripting definition from /usr/bin/osascript; it may not be scriptable.
Hello, I’m /Users/aaron/Desktop/app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

the JXA Release Notes says the following:

**6. Getting the application that is running the script**

```
Application.currentApplication()
```

And yes, I thought it would give me an script object pointing to my script itself, too.

I tested it directly inside the Skript-Editor using your JavaScript:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
console.log('Hello, I’m ' + app.pathTo(this));
```

and the Events tab gave me

```
app = Application("Skript-Editor")
    app.pathTo(null)
    /* Hello, I’m /Users/.../Desktop/app.scpt */
```

When running this app.scpt from `osascript` the function `currentApplication()` returns osascript and the environment warns that the app may not be scriptable... Is it a bug? I don't know, osascript IS the executing app AND it is not scriptable :-/

But otherwise: How can `app` execute the function `pathTo` then and why is `null` passed to it?

just my 2 cents... Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks for the effort and greetings to Hamburg. It also looks like a bug to me—apart from the warning, the script is running totally fine.